# Quickest way to find a text matching control in a control collection

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

We have a C# Windows Forms based application, where there is a panel (for contacts) which holds multiple controls (like name, id, phone etc) under it. We have added a text search (with name, id, phone etc) to display any of the matching contact control by looping (for loop) through each control.

This works well, but if we have more contacts(say more than 100 i.e total of 100 panels) it takes more time. Is there any alternate approach to speed up search in this case?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code below

```
Filter(Control Pls, string search) 
{ 
    foreach (Control ctrl in Pls.Controls) 
    {
        var Name = ctrl.Controls.Find("name", true); 
        if ((Name != null) && (Name.Length != 0)) 
        { 
            Label n = (Label)Name[0]; 
            contactName = n.Text; 
        } 

        var Extn = ctrl.Controls.Find("extn", true); 
        if ((Extn != null) && (Extn.Length != 0)) 
        { 
            Label e = (Label)Extn[0]; 
            contactExtn = e.Text; 
        } if (contactName != null && contactExtn != null) 
        { 
                if (contactName.Contains(search) || contactExtn.Contains(search)) 
                { 
                    ctrl.Show(); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    ctrl.Hide(); 
                } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            ctrl.Hide();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you get matching value then break your loop it and for searching you can use elastic search method which hold indexing concept it surely faster your searching.

Comment: I can't break from the loop, as i had to display all the matching contacts.

Comment: Have you tried linq?

Comment: Does each contact have it's controls on a panel or a user control?

Comment: I have not tried linq yet. Each contact panel has a minimum of five controls in it.

Comment: Linq isn't going to magically make it faster.

Comment: If I create a form with 100 panels, each containing 50 textboxes, then iterating over all and matching their `Text` property to a string, it takes 16 milliseconds on my machine - can you share the code you're currently using to iterate over the controls?

Comment: Here is the code below <br/> Filter(Control Pls, string search)
{
foreach (Control ctrl in Pls.Controls) {
 var Name = ctrl.Controls.Find("name", true);
if ((Name != null) && (Name.Length != 0))
 {
 Label n = (Label)Name[0];
contactName = n.Text;
}
var Extn = ctrl.Controls.Find("extn", true);
if ((Extn != null) && (Extn.Length != 0))
{
Label e = (Label)Extn[0];
contactExtn = e.Text;
}
if (contactName != null && contactExtn != null)
{
if (contactName.Contains(search) || contactExtn.Contains(search))
{
ctrl.Show();
}
else
{
ctrl.Hide();
}
}
 else
{
ctrl.Hide();}
}
}

Comment: @rajkumaradass next time you can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256637/quickest-way-to-find-a-text-matching-control-in-a-control-collection#41256637) button below you post and add anything that you find necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First let me describe my understanding of your situation. I assume that

1. You have contacts stored relational database table, say TContacts
2. For each matching contact found in TContacts, you want to display a
   panel per matched row in the table TContacts
3. Each panel, (say P1,P2, ...) has set of controls to display column-values of the matched
   row

If my understanding is correct then the solution is as under:

1. Use DataTable variable (say VContacts) to store all rows of TContacts table.
2. Add one column (say PanelName) of type string to above DataTable VContacts.
3. Store name of respective panel control for each contact in column PanelName.
4. Use DataTable.Select() method to find out matched contacts
5. Then use PanelName value and find out panel control, use Show() method to display the panel control and hide rest of the panel controls

*NOTE:
If you are not using any database then you need to populate DataTable VContacts through code.*

Comment: I'm not using any database here.